# Asp.Net 4.0 Web Forms -Webpages.Deployment assemblie

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a web application. The platform is Asp.NET 4.0 and I've used web forms. It's not MVC.

I'm getting an error.

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.
```

I've searched and the error is about MVC. I couldn't find any answer why it's happening at webforms. Also the project is working well at localhost. But when I publish it, I am getting that error.

Thanks...

Comment: Did you find the answer? same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a broken reference to a DLL in production - the DLL may not be in the GAC on the machine you pushed to. To verify, you can compare the bin folder locally to that on the production machine.

If it's not available on the deployment machine, right click the reference in your "References" folder and set "Copy Local" to true - then redeploy.